# parsing data to javascript with laravel controller

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

I send data with this code to JS:

```
$user = User::where('id' , $this->selectedItem)->first();
   
$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('userModal', [
    'name' => $user->name,
    'signup' => jdate($user->created_at),
]);
```

‍‍`jDate()` Is a function to convert to Persian date

but in frontend for `signup` I will receive a empty value
and this is JS code to receive data :

```
window.addEventListener('userModal', event => {
    console.log(event.detail);
});
```

Comment: I would start by dumping the returnvalue of that function in PHP first, if you get the name in JS, then there's probably no issue with the data transfer

Comment: @Qirel But the signup value is empty
Of course, when I put it inside the `jDate()` function

Comment: So what you're saying that there's simply no data in the `created_at` column?

Comment: @Qirel No, this column has data. I meant it will not show me date only when I write `jdate($user->created_at)` But if I do not use the jdate function, it shows me the date

Comment: So obviously you need to check that function - you need to share that exact code for the function if you want help with it.

Comment: @Qirel I have put all the code in the question and nothing else...

Comment: @Qirel And when I look at the console logs there is `signup` is empty

Comment: But what is `jdate()`, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: @Qirel that is function from this package morilog/jalali for convert date to persian date or jalali date

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to simply use Carbon instead of jDate().

```
'signup' => \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->created_at)->setTimezone('Asia/Tehran'),
```

Comment: i need persian date !

Comment: Check what timezone a persian date has and then apply it

Comment: The Laravel framework already coverts to a Carbon instance with the timezone of the app, so this is redundant entirely.